# How do I get Survival Time from Survival Models e-g Random Survival Forests?

Tags: time, random-forest, scikit-survival

I want to know how to interpret the output of the RSF when you use .predict? Is it some kind of risk score or survival time? How do I get the values of survival time from the model?

I used the cox proportional hazard model and the random survival forest model. I need the output to be in the form of age or years. I really dont understand what is the output of the models. How do I convert a survival function to extract the time to failure using nay of the survival models?